# What does node distances in numactl mean?

Tags: linux, numa, numactl

I'm trying to understand what `node distances` in `numactl --hardware` mean?

On our cluster, it outputs the following

`numactl --hardware
available: 2 nodes (0-1)
node 0 cpus: 0 1 2 3 4 5 12 13 14 15 16 17
node 0 size: 32143 MB
node 0 free: 188 MB
node 1 cpus: 6 7 8 9 10 11 18 19 20 21 22 23
node 1 size: 32254 MB
node 1 free: 69 MB
node distances:
node   0   1 
  0:  10  21 
  1:  21  10`

This is what I understood so far:

- we have 24 virtual CPUs and that each node has 32Gb of DRAM.
- On a `numa` cluster, we will have to make a "hop" to the next cluster to access the memory on other node and this incurs a higher latency.
- In this context, do the numbers `10` and `21` indicate the latencies for "hops"? How do I find the latency in `ns`? is that specified somewhere?

[This](https://linux.die.net/man/8/numactl) and [this](https://www.sharcnet.ca/help/index.php/Using_numactl) didn't help me much.

EDIT: [This](https://superuser.com/questions/916516/is-the-amount-of-numa-nodes-always-equal-to-sockets) link says that distances are not in `ns`, but are relative distances. how do I get the absolute latency in ns?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To get absolute latency numbers, if you're on an Intel system you can use their Memory Latency Checker tool for any specific system. https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-memory-latency-checker

It prefers to use root/admin powers to disable the hardware prefetching which otherwise skews the numbers, but if you don't have that, the docs also point out that you can ask it to get random elements from the other nodes to get very close to the true numbers e.g.:

```
./mlc --latency_matrix -e -l128 -r
Intel(R) Memory Latency Checker - v3.5
Command line parameters: --latency_matrix -e -l128 -r

Using buffer size of 200.000MB
Measuring idle latencies (in ns)...
                Numa node
Numa node            0       1
       0         112.5   180.3
       1         180.8   112.4
```

Answer (score 0):

`numactl --hardware` gives you stats about the architecture of your hardware, not about on its performance.

If you want the performance characteristics of your hardware you will have to measure it yourself, either by finding an existing one online or writing your own benchmark. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47815885/1411628 will give you an idea on how to get started on writing your own bench.